# Clothe pass through/enter other mesh

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation

It's a been a week since I'm trying to figure out why my cloth pass through other objects. I just want to add a cloth to my final render (img on the right) but it keeps passing through the bottle and the packaging.
I read topics and applied settings like in [**Cloth passes through Rigid Body**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?page=2&tab=Relevance&q=clothe) but same result (image on the left). I rebuilt a side of the packaging without the hole and nothing new. Here is the [**blend file**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gtjBvSsT0m6J1MMO6YKykSACF-7jebma/view?usp=sharing). Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just make a simple demo, it's ok.I think the main problem is your mesh,it's totally disaster...almost no loop quads，it's usually bad to use ngons and connect many lines to one point.Try to make the model again.
[image]

Comment: OMG, thank you! What do you mean by no loop quads? I mean to this shape I started with a plane then extruded to the point when I used the shear tool and extruted again. Do I have to add faces (Ctrl+R) by myself? Clearly mine doesn't have all those vertices.

Comment: modeling looks easy but in fact there are much technique to  learn, especially animate them.Pls refer to this video,you might understand what I'm talking about. Adding faces is meaningless,because your mesh is wrong,blender don't understand what you draw. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQmNXCOh4MM

Comment: I tried to remake the bottle as I know how to do with the packaging but .. Is it the same process?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlDKT.gif

And thanks for the link

Comment: Pls send your demo.It also works to me. I guess maybe you are under the edit mode,pls turn to object mode.

Comment: In the file there is the bottle from my original blender, that is a disaster like the packaging. 
Also there is the bottle in the middle that I built using quads but gives a square shape at the bottom and top rather than round. It works very well like you said.
And there is a bottle that I started with a circle and careful tried to add quad but gives the same effect than original bottle here --> [Blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FiH2gGNWvlr-wnxqsU_ojDJTqIz87IB6/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: two steps:1.ctrl+A, apply scale;2. go to Physics Property in the right, clear all the bake.Then it's ok.

Comment: You're my hero, thank you so much. I have to learn how to use quads because I want to animate most of my stuff now. Thanj you again!